# Vue: Cannot find module '@/views/layout'

Tags: vue.js

When I run the following code, it works fine, Without any errors:

```
item.component = () => import(`@/views/${_component}`)
```

However, when I run the following code, he does not work:

```
item.component = () => import(`@/views/` + _component)
```

Error message:

```
vue-router.esm.js:1897 Error: Cannot find module '@/views/layout'
    at webpackContextResolve (modules sync ^.*$:24)
    at webpackContext (modules sync ^.*$:18)
    at permission.js:40
```

This is weird?

Comment: My purpose is to dynamically load the routing address returned by the server,

Comment: what does eslint say ?

Comment: maybe [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-eslint-dynamic-import-error/55129) can solve the problem ?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw Previously, eslint did not automatically format the code, now it is normal

Comment: ohh. Okay. Happy Coding!

Comment: He still conflicts with eslint，  `ESLint: Cannot read property 'range' of null Occurred while linting`